# notmuch-search: notmuch search process already running for query ‘*’

Tags: notmuch

I'm using emacs+mbsync+notmuch.
When I run `notmuch-poll-and-refresh-this-buffer which run script '.notmuch/hooks/pre-new':

```
#!/bin/sh
mbsync -L gmail
```

Most of the time it gives me a message:

> notmuch-search: notmuch search process already running for query ‘*’

And emails will be not updated. So I have to run it a few times to update my emails.
It's pretty annoying.
How to fix that?